# CountDown Timer and constantly refreshing a label

Tags: c#, sql-server, timer, timeout

I am doing a Auction site
I need help on creating a countdown timer where when the time reach, the product status will change to close
I just compare the differences of the date.

$  if (!IsPostBack)
             {
             SqlDataReader dtrProduct, dtrMinus;

```
         conFindPID = new SqlConnection(strCon);
         conFindPID.Open();
         string conStr = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID=@PID";
         SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand(conStr, conFindPID);
         dtrProduct = cmdCheck.ExecuteReader();
         if (DateTime.Today >= Convert.ToDateTime(dtrProduct["EndingDate"]))
         {
             if (dtrProduct["Status"] == "Open")
             {
                 conFindPID = new SqlConnection(strCon);

                 string conupdate = "UPDATE PRODUCT SET Status=@PS";


                 SqlCommand cmdupdate = new SqlCommand(conupdate, conFindPID);
                 cmdupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PS", "Closing");
                 cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 string conMinus = "SELECT c.*,p.* FROM Customer c,Product p WHERE c.UserID=p.UserID";
                 SqlCommand cmdMinus = new SqlCommand(conMinus, conFindPID);
                 dtrMinus = cmdMinus.ExecuteReader();
                 if (Convert.ToInt32(dtrMinus["Token"]) < Convert.ToInt32(dtrMinus["CurrentBid"]))
                 {


                 }
                 else
                 {
                     int a = Convert.ToInt32(dtrMinus["Token"]) - Convert.ToInt32(dtrMinus["CurrentBid"]);
                     conFindPID = new SqlConnection(strCon);

                     string conComplete = "UPDATE Customer SET Token=@Token";
                     SqlCommand cmdcomplete = new SqlCommand(conComplete, conFindPID);
                     cmdcomplete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Token", a);
                     cmdcomplete.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

1 more thing: I want to keep on refresh a label when there is changes in value
the label is auction current bid where Customer A can direct see the changes if Customer B add more Bid

Comment: What timer are you talking about ? A client side timer hammering your .net backend? If yes, then I dont think it's a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a timer web application, even if you can it is not a good aproach, what if user close the page?

you should write a windows service or sql job for updating sql data which depends on time,
and if you want to refresh label text, you must create a javascript timer and get data by ajax, then set label text with ajax data.

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing a label (or any updating items), you might want to have a look at SignalR, an async signaling library for .NET:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Here's a good Example:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx